# Next button: The next row in the database that does not contain a specific value

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I have a list of articles (of creatures) on my hand coded php website. I want to put a previous and next buttons.

Problem is, each article or creature has a unique id but some creatures have alternative names. In the Database each name is a creature or row in its own right with a unqiue id.

Example: You are on Baba Jaga page (id 150) and the next one in the *database* (id 151) is Baba Yaga (normally all links of Baba Yaga redirect to Baba Jaga). Each creature is referenced as an alternative name (redirect) or unique (page visible to use).

So the next creature from 150 in this example isn't 151 its 152 - Babe the Blue Ox.

What code would I write  to get to the next *Unique* creature in chronological order? Is it a Do while loop or something? Some creatures have many alternative names all next to each other in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use query like this (I don't know your schema, you just forget to post it):

```
SELECT id FROM articles WHERE `id` > 150 AND `type` = 'unique' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I guess 150 becomes a variable of $current_page[id] right? Because of the Limit 1 would it always return the next article in chronological order (that is unique)?

Comment: @Egan7 Ups, I forget about order ;) Updated, now it'll work like you said.